# Unable to Enable Tensorflows Eager execution

Tags: tensorflow, keras, eager-execution

I have an conda environment with Tensorflow 2.0.0-beta1 installed. However whenever I import tensorflow and attempt to enable eager execution I get the error :

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'enable_eager_execution'
```

The only code that I have run for this is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

Is this an error with the tensorflow 2.0 beta module or an issue with my installation ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ternsorflow 2.0 the `enable_eager_execution` method is moved to `tf.compat.v1` module. The following works on tensorflow-2.0.0-beta1

```py
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
```

In tensorflow 2.0 the eager execution is enabled by [default](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/eager). You don't need to enable it in your program.

E.g

```py
import tensorflow as tf

t = tf.constant([5.0])
```

Now you can directly view the value of tensor without using session object.

```py
print(t)
# tf.Tensor([5.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

You can also change the tensor value to numpy array

```py
numpy_array = t.numpy()
print(numpy_array)
# [5.]
```

You can also disable eager execution in tensorflow-2(Tested on tensorflow-2.0.0-beta1. This might not work on future versions.)

```py
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
t2 = tf.constant([5.0])
print(t2)
# Tensor("Const:0", shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

Calling numpy() method on tensor after eager execution is disabled throws an error

```py
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

One issue you should consider while disabling the eager execution is, once the eager execution is disabled it cannot be enabled in the same program, because `tf.enable_eager_execution` should be called at program startup and calling this method after disabling eager execution throws an error:

```py
ValueError: tf.enable_eager_execution must be called at program startup.
```